# Laravel 4 Controller method not found when Capital letter or underscore is used in the middle of the method name

Tags: php, methods, laravel, laravel-4, controller

How do you name controller methods in laravel 4. Big names. `getLogin()` works for me but `getNewLogin()` doesn't work and `getNew_login()` doesn't work either. When I use both of them I get the exception which says

> Controller Method not found.

I am sorry if sounds stupid but I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in the context of using a REST controller, or just a controller method in general? What is the URL that you're trying to access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you use REST controller because you are using `get...()` methods. The camelcases are actually converted to hyphens.

So if you do this:

```
Route::controller('foo', 'FooController');
```

and in your controller:

```
public function getNewLogin()
{
    ...
}
```

You can access your url by `http://localhost/foo/new-login`